# Add value to stdClass Object array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an object like this

```
stdClass Object ([path] => uploads/1482860841920.jpg)
```

and what I want is to add another value that should be comma separated so i can ADD upto 6 value

Like

```
stdClass Object ([path] => uploads/1482860841920.jpg, uploads/1233441234.jpg,..)
```

What I am trying to achieve is update my database field without losing previous upload path and user can keep on adding his uploads path upto 6 values.I didnt find a way to achieve it though mysql so trying with PHP

Its great if I can update this table to

id | path
1  |  uploads/1482860841920.jpg

Like

id | path
1  |  uploads/1482860841920.jpg , uploads/45828gf1920.jpg , ..

without losing old data

Comment: how is mysql involved to that? Can you show what you've tried, cause it's not clear _what_ you want to achieve.

Comment: You should not store multiple values as delimited text values within a single field, enter these values as separate records. You may need to add another table to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = new StdClass;

$object->foo = array("uploads/1482860841920.jpg","uploads/1482860841920.jpg","uploads/1482860841920.jpg");
```

like this to add values..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy solutions to your problem.

The first one is to concatenate the new path to the other ones :

```
if(substr_count($object["path"], ",") < 5){
   $object["path"].=", ".$newPath;
}
```

Then, you can insert the variable directly into your database.

The other solution is to use an array :

```
//initialization
$object["path"] = [];

if(count($object["path"]) < 6){
    $object["path"][] = $newPath;
}
```

And when you want to insert into the database, you [implode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) your array.